# How is the PropertyChanged event used

Tags: mdriven

How is the PropertyChanged event used?
I'm wanting to evaluated the next state of a state machine whenever any property of the class is changed.

Regards Steve

Answer (score 0):

PropertyChanged is part of the standard IPropertyNotifyChanged signaling.

If you want to create side effects if any change is done - consider setting "HasUserCode" on each attribute, Generate code, now you will find a partial method available for you to fill for Set and Get of attributes.

In a setter you can have side effects like running a trigger to step a state machine.